# Akka Streams stop stream after process n elements

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have Akka Stream flow which is reading from file using alpakka, processing data and write into a file. I want to stop flow after processed n elements, count the time of duration and call system terminate. How can I achieve it?

My flow looks like that:

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

 sourceFile ~> mainFlow ~> sinkFile

ClosedShape
})

graph.run()
```

Do you have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with what @Viktor said, first of all you don't need to use the graphDSL to achieve this, and you can use `take(n)` to complete the graph.

Secondly, you can use `mapMaterializedValue` to attach a callback to your Sink materialized value (which in turn should materializes to a `Future[Something]`).

```
  val graph: RunnableGraph[Future[FiniteDuration]] =
    sourceFile
      .via(mainFlow)
      .take(N)
      .toMat(sinkFile)(Keep.right)
      .mapMaterializedValue { f ⇒
        val start = System.nanoTime()
        f.map(_ ⇒ FiniteDuration(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
      }

  graph.run().onComplete { duration ⇒
    println(s"Elapsed time: $duration")
  }
```

Note that you are going to need an `ExecutionContext` in scope.

**EDIT**

Even if you have to use the graphDSL, the same concepts apply. You only need to expose the materialized `Future` of your sink and map on that.

```
  val graph: RunnableGraph[Future[??Something??]] = 
    RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sinkFile) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[Future[Something]] => snk =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    sourceFile ~> mainFlow ~> snk

    ClosedShape
  })

  val timedGraph: RunnableGraph[Future[FiniteDuration]] = 
    graph.mapMaterializedValue { f ⇒
      val start = System.nanoTime()
      f.map(_ ⇒ FiniteDuration(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
    }

  timedGraph.run().onComplete { duration ⇒
    println(s"Elapsed time: $duration")
  }
```

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't specific. My flow is more complicated it is not only: sourceFile ~> mainFlow ~> sinkFile. I wrote it just like an abstraction.  My flow looks something like that: 
`sourceFile ~> bcastA ~> FlowA ~> merge ~> FlowC ~>  bcastA ~> SinkA
                        bcastA ~> FlowB ~> merge                 ~>  bcastA ~> SinkB` So I have to use GraphDSL. Sorry again for confusion.

Comment: Sorry for formatting, I don't know format it properly. By important is that I have multiple flow with broadcasts, merge and multiple Sinks.

Answer (score 2):

No need for GraphDSL here.

```
val doneFuture = (sourceFile via mainFlow.take(N) runWith sinkFile) transformWith { _ => system.terminate() }
```

To obtain time, you can use `akka-streams-contrib`: https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/blob/master/contrib/src/main/scala/akka/stream/contrib/Timed.scala